Visual Studio 2022 C# intellicode not adding closing braces
I'm not sure if it's a bug or under-developed but my Visual Studio 2022 Intellicode does not automatically add closing braces (both on suggestion & format on save).


I do have Automatic brace completion enabled in the options but this does not solve the current issue.
Is there a way to fix this?

Although it appears to be set under "All Languages", can you double check the language specific section and ensure it's still enabled there. Sometimes disabling and re-enabling options can cause things to start working again too.

yes i have checked both "All Languages" and "C#" sections before posting here, tried  disabling & re-enabling the option several times but didn't work out.

@Tim May I know if you get any chance to check my answer and the error report?

@MinxinYu-MSFT I have already seen the error report before posting here and the it  doesn't really help as it is being investigated. The solution you suggested doesn't solve the issue either because the intellicode does not suggest correct method/class/etc. When I type my own line of code, the intellicode no longer suggests anything else hence not closing the braces.

Generally, Microsoft gives priority to fixing the most concerned problems. You can leave comments and vote the report to attract Microsoft's attention.

This issue is currently being investigated by Developer Community.
You haven't completed the code after {,
for example:
 int[] array = new int[] { 5 };

for (int i = 0; i < array.Length; i++) {

Then input console. It will complete the brace.

Error report:
There are issues with Intellicode in VS2022, you can follow this thread and post your comments to get Microsoft's attention.
IntelliCode Suggestion Issue: Block Code Not Closed Automatically
